# Can I specify which reducer to dispatch to in ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I just started using redux and am wondering if there is a **clean** way to use multiple reducers. More specifically, I'm wondering if there is a way to specify which reducer I wish to dispatch an action to

Example) Say I have two reducers : userReducer, postReducer

User Reducer

```
export function userReducer(state: User, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {]
    case SOME_ACTION:
      return state;
    default:
      return state || new User();
  }
}
```

PostReducer

```
export function postReducer(state: Post, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {]
    case SOME_OTHER_ACTION:
      return state;
    default:
      return state || new Post();
  }
}
```

Initialized by

```
StoreModule.provideStore({user: userReducer, post: postReducer}),
```

I want to be able to call something like

```
const store = this._store.select<User>('user');
store.dispatch({type: SOME_ACTION, payload: {blah: 'blah'}})
```

and have only userReducer be called.

Currently when I dispatch an action, both `userReducer` and `postReducer` update their states. Is this the *de facto* way in which redux works?

If not, is there a clean way to achieve this? It seems odd that all reducers are updated for every dispatch.

### **Update**

I'm asking this question because of the following part.

```
default:
  return state || new User();
```

It doesn't seem like good practice to return default by checking whether state is null. I want to be able to do the following.

```
default:
  return new User();
```

Currently I can't do this because if I dispatch `SOME_ACTION`, both `postReducer.default` and `userReducer.SOME_ACTION` will be invoked.

Not only this, but I can imagine a scenario where debugging would be a nightmare if I accidentally create an action with the same string for two reducers as both of them would be called.

Comment: Could you please speficy *why* it bothers you that every reducer is called on every dispatch? Do you have a specific problem that arises with this behaviour, or do you just think it's odd? I ask, because the answer could just be 'that's how redux works', or a deeper misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short ***no, you cannot dispatch an action to a subset of the registered reducers.*** (At least not in a clean way and I reckon not without changing the @ngrx/store-implementation itself...)

It is indeed the way redux works: everytime an action is dispatched, the store calls all reducer-functions with the current state + action and expects a (new) state back. If a reducer should not react to an action it has to return the unaltered state it has been called with (through the `default` case). *(In my opinion that is one of the major strengths of redux because it allows you to react to the same action in different reducers)*

To achieve the behaviour you want, I suggest that you keep the state initialization and the default case separated:

```
export const initialState: User = new User();

export function userReducer(state: User = initialState, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOME_ACTION:
            /* Work with the state and return a new state */
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

On bootstrap, all reducer-functions get called with an undefined state and an init-action. By using a default parameter (`initialState`) the state will be initialised with whatever `new User()` is. It also allows you to set `initialState = undefined` if you don't want to initialize the state right away. (I wrote an answer about store-initialisation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822967/ngrx-how-are-states-combined-and-initialized/43825941#43825941), if you are interested).

I'm afraid you have to accept, that you can't do

```
default:
   return new User();
```

because it would reset every slice of the state to a default-state (`new User()`), as you have noticed.

> Not only this, but I can imagine a scenario where debugging would be a nightmare if I accidentally create an action with the same string for two reducers as both of them would be called.

You are correct, it could happen that you accidentally name two actions the same. One way to mitigate this problem is shown in the [ngrx-example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/actions/book.ts):

```
export const SEARCH =           '[Book] Search';
export const SEARCH_COMPLETE =  '[Book] Search Complete';

export class SearchAction implements Action {
    readonly type = SEARCH;

    constructor(public payload: string) { }
}

export class SearchCompleteAction implements Action {
    readonly type = SEARCH_COMPLETE;

    constructor(public payload: Book[]) { }
}

export type Actions
  = SearchAction
  | SearchCompleteAction
```

Notice that every action-string is prefixed with the entities name. In addition, this approach allows for typechecking the payload when doing an action-dispatch.
If you are really paranoid about two actions being named the same, you could name them `const MY_ACTION = '[Entity] MY_ACTION_565ef1b6-2c78-47b0-9b61-499ba9da3dde'` (a random GUID), it really doesn't matter.
An action dispatch would still look the same:

```
import * as book from '../actions/book';

this.store.dispatch(new book.SearchAction('hello'));
```

Unless you are developing an app that has a *huge* team working on it, I would say the chances of two actions being named the same are very slim. I have also seen people checking for duplicate action names on app-initialisation, although I can't find an example right now.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I specify which reducer to dispatch to in ngrx

No and it's by design. Every action is dispatched to every reducer, and in your reducers you just decide whether you want to handle it or not. As your state in reducer should be immutable, if you don't handle a particular action, just return the untouched state.

Instead of that here's how you can handle it :

```
function myReducer(state = someInitialState, action) {
  case (action.type):
    'ACTION_1': 
      ...
    'ACTION_2': 
      ...

    default: 
      return state;
}
```

This way, when your state is undefined, it'll be set to the initial value `someInitialState`.

And if you don't handle an action, the same state will be returned.

That said, this is basic `Redux` and I highly recommend you to take a look into http://redux.js.org before digging into `ngrx`.